# \n not working when printing to txt file

Tags: java, java-io

Trying to write a string to a text file, which works, but doesn't include the `newline \n` part. Can someone tell me why it won't work? `\t` works fine but this just wont.

FileReader class:

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileReader
{
    public static void readFile()
    {
        try
        {
            PrintWriter f;
            File file = new File("../webapps/Assignment1/Seats.txt");
            if(!file.exists())
            {
                f = new PrintWriter(file);
                f.write(populateSeats());
                f.close();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String populateSeats()
    {
        String rowID[] = {"A", "B", "C" ,"D" ,"E" ,"F" ,"G" ,"H"};
        String seatPop = "";
        int rowCount = 0;
        int colCount = 1;

        for(int r = 0; r < 8; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < 8; c++)
            {
                seatPop += "SeatID: " + rowID[rowCount] + colCount + "\n";
                seatPop += "Avail: True \n";
                seatPop += "UserID: null\n";
                seatPop += "Phone: null\n";
                seatPop += "Address: null\n";
                seatPop += "Email: null\n";
                colCount++;
            }
            colCount = 1;
            rowCount++;
        }
        return seatPop;
    }
}
```

Main class (Just makes an instance of FileReader and then run the method)

```
FileReader file = new FileReader();

file.readFile();
```

Comment: Please use ` System.lineSeparator()` instead `\n`

Comment: $ hexdump ../webapps/Assignment1/Seats.txt ... the '\n' is most probably there ... ('\n' == 0x0a)

Answer (score 3):

I speculate that the `\n` are in fact being written to the file, but that the system you are using does not use `\n` as the line separator.  If so, then these characters would be present, be they might be getting rendered as newlines in your editor.  Instead, try using a system independent line separator:

```
System.lineSeparator();     // Java 7 or later; I'll assume this is your case
```

In your code you might do this:

```
 for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
    seatPop += "SeatID: " + rowID[rowCount] + colCount + System.lineSeparator();
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, I'd up vote but I have bad rep apparently

Answer (score -1):

When adding a new line for files on windows use `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

`\n` was made specificly for Unix / Linux Systems.

`\r\n` will add a new line when being used on windows.

So in your code change it to

```
for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
seatPop += "SeatID: " + rowID[rowCount] + colCount + "\r\n";
// .....
}
```

However as Tim said in his answer above, the best way would be to use the `System.lineSeparator();` method as this will return the proper escape sequence to generate a new line independent of the operating system. As such I would reccomend you use `System.lineSeparator();` over `\r\n`.

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations_in_different_character_encoding_specifications to understand why your answer is misleading

Comment: Not my downvote, and this may solve the immediate problem, but it still leaves open the possibility that another platform might use a different line ending, and the problem could still happen there.

Comment: This works too, thanks! Comments say don't use this one though so I'll use other one